# How can I use a cmd variable in an osql command?

Tags: sql, cmd, osql

I'm trying to run an osql command from a cmd shell. I need to use a cmd level variable within my osql command.

For example, I have a variable %mydate%, and I want to pass it in as the value for the @start_date parameter in the following osql call.

```
osql -Sdb -Uautosys -Pdata_load -ddms -Q"EXEC dbo.sp @start_time = '' "
```

How can I do this?

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
osql -Sdb -Uautosys -Pdata_load -ddms -Q"EXEC dbo.sp @start_time = '%mydate%' "
```

dos substitution happens quite early, so osql shouldn't see the actual string `%mydate%`

Comment: That's what I was trying, but it didn't work. I assumed that I had the wrong method of doing it. Turns out that my variable was null, so I was having problems.

Do you know how to concatenate two variables in a cmd shell? Maybe I'll post that as a different question...

Comment: @chama: SET foo = %firstOne%%SecondOne%

Comment: That's what I thought, but it doesn't work. My code is `set mydate2 = %mydate%%Time%`.

Comment: @chama: %Time% is special/reserved. Was this intended? http://www.computerhope.com/sethlp.htm. And thank you for the rep :-)

Comment: Might have just needed a space, e.g. `set mydate2 = %mydate% %Time%`